# centering equation and caption in Inderscience template

Tags: floats, equations

Below is my minimal code..It is an inderscience single columned template.
I have two problems:

First is, I would like to bring the equation somewhere near to the center. In my code it is aligned to the left.

Secondly, i would like to center my figure caption.  When i use 
`\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}`, it throws the error `\Center already defined`.

```
\documentclass{singlecol-new}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}


\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\captionsetup[justification=centering]{caption}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}

\theoremstyle{TH}{
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corrolary}[lemma]{Corrolary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{claim}[lemma]{Claim}
\newtheorem{stheorem}[lemma]{Wrong Theorem}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
}

\theoremstyle{THrm}{
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{scheme}{Scheme}
}

\theoremstyle{THhit}{
\newtheorem{case}{Case}[section]
}

\makeatletter
\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Biomedical research becomes reliant on multi-disciplinary,
multi-institutional collaboration, and data sharing is becoming increasingly important for researchers to reuse experiments, pool expertise and validate approaches. However, there are many hurdles for data sharing, including the unwillingness to share,  lack of flexible data model for providing context information for shared data,  difficulty to share syntactically and semantically consistent data across distributed institutions, and expensive cost to provide tools to share the data.  In our work,  we develop a Web-based collaborative biomedical data sharing platform {\em SciPort} to support biomedical data sharing across distributed organizations. SciPort provides a generic metadata model for researchers to flexibly customize and organize the data. To enable convenient data sharing, SciPort provides a central server based data sharing architecture, where data can be shared by one click through publishing metadata to the central server. To enable consistent data sharing, SciPort provides collaborative distributed schema management across distributed sites. To enable semantic consistency for data sharing, SciPort provides semantic tagging through controlled vocabularies. SciPort is lightweight and can be easily deployed for building data sharing communities for biomedical research.
\end{abstract}

\KEYWORD{Metadata; Scientific Data Management; Data Sharing;  Data Integration; Computer Supported Collaborative Work.}


 \section{Introduction}

%The needs for data sharing
With increased complexity of scientific problems, biomedical
research is increasingly a collaborative effort across multiple
institutions and disciplines.  Data sharing is becoming critical for
validating approaches and ensuring that future research can build on
previous efforts and discoveries. As a result, data sharing is often
required by scientific funding agencies to share the data produced
in grant projects. For example,  the National Institutes of Health
(NIH) of US requires data sharing for NIH funded projects of
\$500,000 or more in direct costs in any one year.


\begin{equation}
    r_i(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
    n_i(t)          &   \textrm{if $H_0$} \\
    h_i(t).s(t)+ n_i(t) &  \textrm{if $H_1$}  \label{eq:energy} 
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    Y_i \sim \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
    \chi^2_{2LW} &  \textrm{if $H_0$} \\
    \chi^2_{2LW} (2\gamma_i)      &   \textrm{if $H_1$} \label{eq:distribution}
    \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

To support large scale collaborative biomedical research, NIH
provides large-scale collaborative project awards  for a team of
independently funded investigators to synergize and integrate their
efforts, and the awards mandate the research results and data to be
shared (\cite{Meng}).  The Network for
Translational Research (NTR): Optical Imaging in Multimodality
Platforms (\cite{Silva}) is one of such collaborative projects on the
development, optimization, and validation of imaging methods and
protocols for rapid translation to clinical environments.  It
requires not only managing the complex scientific research results,
but also sharing the data across hundreds of research collaborators.
As another example, Siemens Healthcare has research collaborations
with hundreds of research sites distributed across the US, each
providing Siemens marketing support by periodically delivering white
papers, case reports, clinic methods, clinic protocols,
state-of-the-art images, etc. In the past, there were no convenient
methods for research partners to share data with Siemens, and mostly
data were delivered through media such as emails, CDs and hard
copies. This made it very difficult to organize, query and integrate
the shared data.

\begin{figure*}
   \centering
    \caption{Payoff of a cooperating and non-cooperating SU when S=10,  $\sigma_{s}^2$=-9dB, $C_{d}$=0.81, $C_{s}$=0.6}
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in,height=2.5in]{PrisonerDile1}
\label{PrisonerDile1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \caption{Illustration of TFT strategy without collision }
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in,height=2.5in]{rosette}
\label{rosette}
\end{figure*}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Silva et al.}{2007}]{Silva}
Da Silva, C., Choi, B., \& Kim, K.(2007) `Distributed Spectrum Sensing for Cognitive Radio Systems', \textit{Information Theory and Applications Workshop}, La Jolla, CA, Jan. 29 -Feb. 2 2007, pp.120-123.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Meng et al.}{2010}]{Meng}
Meng, J., Yin, W., Li, H., Houssain, E., \& Han, Z. (2010). Collaborative spectrum Sensing from sparse observations using matrix completion for cognitive radio networks. \textit{IEEE International Conference on Acoustics Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP)}, Dallas, TZ, March 2010, pp. 3114-3117,.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is minimal!

Comment: Whatever else you do, please also fix several glaring errors in the bib items. E.g., when readers come across a city named "Dallas, TZ", not only will they note that there's an obvious error in the bibliography, their confidence in the correctness of the rest of the paper will also drop immediately.

Comment: The document class `singlecol-new` doesn't seem to be included in standard TeX distributions. Where might it be obtained from?

Answer (score 1):

*Answer to the first question:*

The alignment of `equation` is redefined in the document class you have used, ie. `singlecol-new`.  Following is the amended code, which will bring the equations centered.

```
\def\equation{\@beginparpenalty\predisplaypenalty
  \@endparpenalty\postdisplaypenalty
  \refstepcounter{equation}\EQtrivlist \item[]\leavevmode
  \hbox to\linewidth\bgroup\hfill $\m@th\displaystyle}

\def\endequation{$\hfill\displaywidth\linewidth\@eqnnum%
\egroup\endEQtrivlist}
```

[image]

With regard to the second query, the figure caption is perfectly centered in my PDF output. You may ensure that you are using the latest version of `caption` package.  My package shows the version:

```
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)Customizing captions (AR)
```

[image]

Comment: regarding centering caption when i use that package and compile i got error as \Center already defined or \end illegal

Comment: Since the problem remains only at your end, then the best option would be to proceed without `caption` package, but you can use the amended code from the same `class ` file, here it is:

`\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\parindent0pt
  \ifx\@captype\@tabtxt
  \else\NINE\centering
  \par\noindent{\fignamefont #1:\HD{7}{0}}\quad
  #2\vspace{6pt} \fi}`

Comment: Please ensure to give `\makeatletter` before these lines and `\makeatother` at the end.

Comment: that worked great for caption...thank u so much..but regarding centering equation, after using that code, i get an error  you cant use \space factor in vertical mode @Sunilkumar

Comment: I have appended the my preamble part as _Another Answer_ below which I used to obtain the correct result.  Please use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the preamble I used to obtain the perfect results.

```
\documentclass{singlecol-new}

\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{array}

%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\captionsetup[justification=centering]{caption}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}

\theoremstyle{TH}{
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corrolary}[lemma]{Corrolary}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{claim}[lemma]{Claim}
\newtheorem{stheorem}[lemma]{Wrong Theorem}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
}

\theoremstyle{THrm}{
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{scheme}{Scheme}
}

\theoremstyle{THhit}{
\newtheorem{case}{Case}[section]
}

\makeatletter
\def\theequation{\arabic{equation}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\def\equation{\@beginparpenalty\predisplaypenalty
  \@endparpenalty\postdisplaypenalty
  \refstepcounter{equation}\EQtrivlist \item[]\leavevmode
  \hbox to\linewidth\bgroup\hfill $\m@th\displaystyle} %$
\def\endequation{$\hfill\displaywidth\linewidth\@eqnnum%$
  \egroup\endEQtrivlist}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\parindent0pt
  \ifx\@captype\@tabtxt
  \else\NINE\centering
  \par\noindent{\fignamefont #1:\HD{7}{0}}\quad
  #2\vspace{6pt} \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
```